# Merge all double items in list and multiply amount

Tags: javascript

I'm a student learning React Native, and I'm trying to merge my list of objects to get the total amount by product name. The list looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 125,
        "amountUnit": "gr",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Tarwebloem" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 1,
        "amountUnit": "tl",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Zonnebloem olie" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 3,
        "amountUnit": "st",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Eieren" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 1,
        "amountUnit": "tl",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Zonnebloem olie" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 125,
        "amountUnit": "gr",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Tarwebloem" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 3,
        "amountUnit": "st",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Eieren" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 125,
        "amountUnit": "gr",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Tarwebloem" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 1,
        "amountUnit": "tl",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Zonnebloem olie" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 1,
        "amountUnit": "tl",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Zonnebloem olie" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 3,
        "amountUnit": "st",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Eieren" }
    },
    {
        "amount": 125,
        "amountUnit": "gr",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Tarwebloem" }
    }
]
```

I want to delete the duplicates, but also I want to calculate the amount with each other to get the total of amount like this:

```
[
    {
        "amount": **500**,
        "amountUnit": "gr",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Tarwebloem" }
    },
    {
        "amount": **4**,
        "amountUnit": "tl",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Zonnebloem olie" }
    },
    {
        "amount": **9**,
        "amountUnit": "st",
        "productID": { "jumboID": [], "name": "Eieren" }
    },
]
```

I can't really figure it out by myself. Hope someone can help me with it.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Have a look to the Array.prototype.reduce() method. It may help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getSumForEach = (arr) => {
    let result = [];

    arr.forEach((element) => { // map through arr an make every item as element
    const foundObject = result.find(obj => obj.amountUnit === element.amountUnit);// Try to find in "result" an object with the same amountUnit as the element amountUnit
        if(foundObject) { // if foundObject is defined so the above code has found an item in result with the same amountUnit as the element
            foundObject.amount += element.amount; // we add  the amount of element to the found object amount
        }else { // undefind ie not found
            result.push(element) // we add element to result    
        }     
    })

    return result; // return the `result` array as result of the funtion
}
```

**Note:** if some elements of `arr` have different `productID` so the the `productID` of the first found element will be the `productID` of the object in the returned array